# Postfix - 5.7.1 relay access denied

Tags: postfix, redhat, permissions

I'm running `postfix` on `RHEL6`:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
# rpm -q postfix
postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_5.x86_64
#
```

I'm trying to implement following:

`/etc/postfix/access` - access - Postfix SMTP server access table:

```
#        /etc/postfix/main.cf:
#            smtpd_client_restrictions =
#                check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/access
# 
#        /etc/postfix/access:
#            1.2.3   REJECT
#            1.2.3.4 OK
# 
#        Execute  the  command  "postmap /etc/postfix/access" after
#        editing the file.
```

`postconf` - Postfix configuration utility:

```
# postconf -n | grep access
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/access
#
```

`/etc/postfix/access(.db)`:

```
# grep -v ^# access 
10.52.11.97 OK
#
```

`postmap` - Postfix lookup table management:

```
# postmap /etc/postfix/access
# echo $?
0
#
```

whenever trying to relay email, I'm getting following:

`/var/log/maillog`:

```
postfix/smtpd[1515]: connect from X.X.X[10.52.11.97]
postfix/smtpd[1515]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from X.X.X[10.52.11.97]: 554 5.7.1 <X@X.X>: Relay access denied; from=<X@X.X> to=<X@X.X> proto=SMTP helo=<HELO>
postfix/smtpd[1515]: lost connection after RCPT from X.X.X[10.52.11.97]
postfix/smtpd[1515]: disconnect from X.X.X[10.52.11.97]
```

**UPDATE**

per @yoonix, @masegaloeh, I'm posting 'smtpd_*_restrictions' as well:

```
$ egrep 'smtp.*restriction' *
access:#               text of smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions.
access:#            smtpd_client_restrictions =
main.cf:# through Postfix.  See the smtpd_recipient_restrictions parameter
main.cf:# relay mail to.  See the smtpd_recipient_restrictions description in
master.cf:#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
master.cf:#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
master.cf:#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
master.cf:#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
master.cf:#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
master.cf:#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
master.cf:#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
master.cf:#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
$
```

seems like everything is commented out.

Comment: smtpd_client_restrictions specifies what clients are allowed to CONNECT.  It has nothing to do with relaying.  If you've configured relaying, you haven't included it here.

Comment: You should post smtpd_*_restriction here. Postfix evaluated *every* restriction stage even you allowed it in earlier stage.

Comment: @yoonix that makes sense, so I took it out.

Comment: @masegaloeh I updated my question with additional information.

Comment: I added my `10.52.11.97/32` to `$mynetworks` and it seems to be working fine now. I guess the question is this is considers to be best practice or I should consider doing it through another route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should tell us about your goal AND attempted solution. Without goal, we can't give you alternative solution.

Looking from the comment, looks like you want to whitelist some client to relay via your server. Postfix itself [has ACL-relay mechanism](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html) via smtpd_*_restriction. To know what enabled ACL in  postfix, you can run command

```
postconf | grep _restrictions
```

By default, postfix only shipped by `permit_mynetworks`, `permit_sasl_authenticated` and `defer_unauth_destination` in `smtpd_relay_restrictions`. That means, postfix will

1. permit relay if client come from IP address defined in `mynetworks` parameter
2. permit relay if client has successfully authenticated via SASL
3. soft reject email if recipient domain not listed in postfix address class.
4. Otherwise, permit the relay

*You can also get the information about that parameter via [man 5 postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) page.*

That's explain why postfix allow relay from specific client [when you place the its IP address in `mynetworks` parameter](https://serverfault.com/questions/663569/postfix-5-7-1-relay-access-denied#comment809723_663569).

---

Regarding your initial solution via `check_client_access`, it should work too IF you place it before defer_unauth_destination. So, you must put this configuration in `main.cf`

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/access, defer_unauth_destination
```

Put it `smtpd_client_restrictions` won't work because postfix will checks the restriction each stage (..., client, helo, sender, relay, recipient, ...). For further info you can refer to [Postfix SMTP relay and access control](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html) page

Comment: I _REALLY_ appreciate such a great depth of your answer, I understand `postfix` much better now. Thanks again!